# Fastest way to read QR codes Client vs Server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, qr-code

I am in the design stages of an app involving QR codes. It will be a contest where a user sees a QR code and scans it. The first user to scan the QR code is the winner.

Because the contest is on a first come first serve basis I want to make sure that the first user who scans the code is the winner. I have noticed that (at least from what I have read) there are Javascript and C# ways to read QR codes (Is there a JQuery way?).

Which way would be the fastest/fairest/most efficient? Assume that there will be many many people scanning a QR code at once. I want to makes sure that the first guy who scans it is the winner, and not get into issues because his request wasn't processed fast enough.

I guess the real question I would be asking would be this: **When there are many users attempting one action on one app, would a client side or server side method work better? Would the differences have an effect like I am worried about?** ect.

Comment: What is the contest and what sort of tolerances are you expecting? Is this a quick-draw western-gunfight type thing? Are you racing cars with built in cameras down a track? Or are people doing a whole day scavenger hunt across a city where getting the timings down to a nano-second not a huge deal?

Comment: Without going into to much detail it will be something like this. A bunch of users will be in the same area (like a theater) and a QR code will appear at some random time (on a screen). Then the first user to scan it will be the winner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two stages to scanning a QR code.

1. Capturing the image
2. Converting the image to text

Step 1 has to be done on the client.

Then it becomes a question of "Client CPU power + time to send the text data" Vs. "Server CPU power (shared between clients) + time to send the image data".

Client CPU power is variable. Bandwidth is variable. Latency is variable. You'll need to provide the server with more CPU power and bandwidth per user if you want the decoding to happen there.

You can, of course, measure the time from when the image was uploaded instead of decoded if you go with the "send the image" approach.

So, in conclusion:

> would a client side or server side method work better?

Both will some of the time.

Comment: That works for me. I have code to do it server side anyways, so if there about the same then I can save time and reuse that

Answer (score 1):

Either way the process of decoding the image will take some time, and that varies depending on the client CPU or the network speed.

Once you have captured the image on the client, you could request a token/timestamp from the server. That will be a small request, so the network speed will not affect it much. Then you can proceed to either decode the image on the client or send i to the server to be decoded.

If two users come in close in time, you know which one captured the image first from their tokens.

Answer (score 1):

On a modern smartphone, detecting and decoding a QR code is something that can happen in under 100ms. I doubt variability in the client-side would produce any meaningful unfairness. But, I certainly think the client-side variability is smaller than the network variability which would come into play when uploading images rather than decoding client side.